# 3d model exported with textures from Blender and imported as .fbx now has different texture size

Tags: modeling, texturing, .fbx

I created a 3d model from scratch in Blender with custom textures added in Blender so when I exported the 3d model I created in Blender as .fbx and imported that in Blender or view it in another .fbx viewer program then the textures are way bigger and it does not look like the 3d model I created

in Blender so how can I export 3d models I made in Blender and make sure the textures stay the same look when I view it in other 3d programs? I am using Blender 2.93. Please be nice I'm new to Blender and I can't find an answer to this question online.

**Made from Blender**

[image]

**Exported from Blender as .fbx how it looks in every 3d program including Blender**

[image]

**Just in case you guys ask what settings I used**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do your material nodes look like? Compare them on the original and reimported model.

Comment: I think this problem has popped up here before. If you are not altering/transforming the texture coordinates with your shader nodes (and are using UV texture coordinates), this is either a limitation of the FBX format, or of Blender's exporter. Try exporting as OBJ, perhaps?

Comment: Hello @scurest thanks for the reply I updated my post to show what settings I used and they are both different the fbx import don't have a texture coordinate nor a mapping in the shading section but instead has a normalMap setting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TheLabCat yeah I am using the shader section to manipulate the textures. I updated the post with more screen shots and I think it will act the same regardless if I export it as OBJ or not. Well let me try to do that and see what happens hopefully exporting it as OBJ will keep the same look.

Comment: I see. Yeah, that transform node won’t be exported. I recommend baking the textures or just scaling the UV’s instead by hand.

Comment: The mapping node is doing nothing, it doesn't matter whether its exported. You can't export Generated texture coordinates though. You'll have to UV unwrap your mesh.

Comment: Thanks @TheLabCat your suggestion on texture baking helped out I went on google to find tutorials on texture baking and I found a short to the point video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLQFopN--LY and I was able to export it as .obj and link the texture to the 3d model and it worked. The thing that sucks is that I could not directly and successfully export it as .fbx from some reason it made it very buggy so I had to convert the .obj file in blender to a .glb file and then convert the .glb to a .fbx file to get it to work as a exported .fbx file. Strange huh? Now I have a new issue.

Comment: And that new issue is I tried texture baking on a multi texture 3d model and it was easy to understand how to save all those multi textures and link them to the .obj's .mtl file. But the issue now is that it works to an extent on multi texture 3d models meaning I will get all the textures right except some areas of the 3d model will have white blank areas but I know for sure this method works on single texture 3d models but this method seems to be glitchy on multi textures. Perhaps I can go more in depth about this new issue in a new post. @TheLabCat

Comment: @MichaelNunez That sounds like an issue possibly worthy of a new post, since it seems pretty separate from the current issue at hand. I pray you well.